# How do I reset UI panel zoom level?

Tags: interface, customization

I zoomed in / out of one of my UI panels and I can't figure out how to zoom back out/ in to get it normal size.

How can I reset the zoom level of UI panels?

Answer (score 37):

Panels and other user interface dialogs can be customized to your personal preference. One example for customization is the horizontal or vertical alignment. Another is zoom factor.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/tabs_panels.html

The panel focused by the mouse pointer can be zoomed in and out by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> and moving the mouse up and down.

Alternatively you can use <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> while hovering over the panel.

**To reset the zoom factor to default, focus the panel with the mouse pointer and press** <kbd>Home</kbd>.
On a MacBook (Pro), use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

This will reset zoom to the default which is dependent on the DPI settings configured in system preferences:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/interface.html?highlight=dpi

Comment: The Home button is also useful in the animation timeline for zooming to focus on the range between the start and end frames.