# How to increase/decrease the size of the buttons inside the panels?

Tags: interface

I've downloaded a .blend file recently and all of the interface elements look very small. I remember that there were an easy trick to make everything bigger (or smaller) when I was using Blender 2.49 long time ago. My question is how to do it increase or decrease the size of the buttons within the panels using User Preferences and without using it?
[image]

Comment: You can go to File Menu/User Preferences/System in section General Adjust the DPI value

Comment: One way I recall is by using `-` or `+` Numpad buttons while hovering mouse over adjacent menu.

Comment: If this is happening on a file you didn't create, and want to preserve your own default layout,  uncheck the LoadUI box when loading the file. http://i.stack.imgur.com/5m27W.png

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18615/how-do-i-reset-ui-panel-zoom-level

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27016/make-blender-usable-on-high-resolution-screen-on-windows/27028#27028

Comment: @cegaton, could you transform your comment to the answer? Your solution is very helpful and valuable.

Comment: The title of this question doesn't seem to match the content at the minute, the title before the edit seemed fine.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot, I guess you're right. I'll get back to the previous edit of this question and ask a new- modified one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to the panel you want to change then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and push the <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd>. If you move your mouse up, the keys get bigger if you move down the keys get smaller.

Answer (score 4):

In order to restore the panel size to the *default setting* move the mouse cursor over the panel and press <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: Then it's a dupe?

Answer (score 4):

pressing **<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>** or **<kbd>Numpad -</kbd>** you can zoom in or out on any window (or control) in Blender.

To resize the panel drag it with the left mouse button.

[image]

As an alternative, if this is happening on a file you didn't create, you can preserve your own default layout, uncheck the LoadUI box when loading the file.

[image]