# Scroll wheel zoom is unmanageble

Tags: customization

There seems to be no way to limit the speed of the zoom using the scroll wheel.  It behaved better after selecting 'auto depth' but after a restart even that had no effect.  The zoom function is a major navigational aspect and needs to be more refined.  Is there some setting or feature I'm missing here?

Comment: To have more control over zooming do it with the *Ctrl+Mouse Scroll*. Hold *Ctrl* and *Mouse Scroll* then drag the cursor up or down.

Comment: Auto Depth had no effect after restarting because new user preferences configuration likely wasn't saved. Check also if Pivot point is set to something other than 3D cursor, e.g. set it to Median Point.

Comment: You should be able to change your scroll wheel sensitivity at the OS level. Take a look in your system prefs.

Comment: @Mentalist While changing the scroll wheel sensitivity from the OS level may solve this problem, it is bad practice to change it every now and then, say to surf through the internet normally.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue recently on Windows. I usually use Linux, but opened a file I'd been working on in Windows, and the scroll wheel zoom was WAY OFF!

Basically, with the panel in focus, hit the "Home" key. Found this answer [HERE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18615/how-do-i-reset-ui-panel-zoom-level?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

With Blender on Windows, you may hold <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> on your keyboard and <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> while moving the mouse itself up and down rather than the just scroll wheel to get finer control. I seem to be able to zoom in/out slowly and smoothly or quickly like this.