# Font too small in tool shell

Tags: customization

I have to clarify that this is only the case in one file and only in the bottom of the tool shell
[image]

Blender kept crashing when I tried to convert hair particles to mesh on windows so I went to Ubuntu and converted them there however I must've pressed something there because the font on the bottom of the tool shell is suddenly small

What I've tried :

*reset theme to default

*make side by side comparison of the "broken" user preferences with the user preferences of a new project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zoom individual panels in and out. Try pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> while hovering your mouse over the keyboard.

[Similar Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18615/how-do-i-reset-ui-panel-zoom-level)